# Use a DTS Connect enabled sound card in Ubuntu

Tags: pulseaudio, soundcard, spdif

I recently bought a DTS Connect enabled sound card (Asus Xonar DS). I plugged it in and connected it to my AV via SPDIF. Stereo sound works and pass-through via VLC works too. The problem is that there is no option in Pulseaudio for 5.1 through SPDIF. Do I need to download a special driver or is there a configuration I need to make?

Answer (score -2):

S/PDIF supports the following formats:

Single channel PCM (Mono)

Dual channel PCM (Stereo)

Compressed bitstreams up to 48Khz/16bps using AC3 (Dolby Digital) or DTS encoding mechanisms.

Surround audio across S/PSIF can only be achieved using AC3/DTS. Multichannel PCM (most desirable) is not possible over S/PDIF but is possible over HDMI.

If you wish to use your external amplifier to play games that do not have native support for AC3 (almost none on PC do as it's typically unnecessary) then you must have a soundcard that supports Dolby Digital Live or DTS Connect, and an external receiver which supports decoding either one.

Comment: Yes, I know. I said that the sound card supports DTS Connect and the receiver is compatible. I just can't enable DTS Connect.